# Why is Wolfram Alpha showing me this function has no roots; or does it actually have no roots?

Tags: roots, wolfram-alpha

I am currently trying to find the roots of this function below.

$$ f_s(c,s,\alpha,\rho, \gamma, us) =(\alpha s^{\rho-1} ((1-\alpha)c^\rho + \alpha s^\rho)^{((1-\gamma)/\rho) - 1}) - us $$

, where us is one whole variable.

I want to find the roots of this function, given fixed values of s,alpha,rho,gamma and us. The issue is, I have typed this function into wolfram trying different fixed values, but the result is always that it yields no roots.

s = 40, alpha = 0.5, rho = 0.5, gamma = 2, us = 3
[image]

s = 20, alpha = 0.2, rho = 0.5, gamma = 2, us = 2
[image]

Is there something I'm missing or does this equation truly have no roots? I've attached some more images below that might be of help, thanks a lot!

---

Wolfram Alpha Giving the Origin of that function above, and us is just a new variable I made up to subtract from it.

EDIT 1 : Thank you for all your suggestions; I have tried graphing it, and for sure there are no roots. This is supposed to work with either of the fixed values I chose, so I would conclude that this function really has no roots and I was down the wrong track. If anyone else has any insights, that would be great but if not, thanks for your help everyone and I'll close this thread.

[image]

Comment: It may be a good idea to plot one of your no-root examples: if it really has no roots, that should be obvious from the graph.

Comment: First of all, it sounds like you are trying to find the roots of a function in *one* variable ($c$). I would not confuse WolframAlpha with six other symbols if you actually know their values. Second, do you have any reason to believe a solution exists?

Comment: It looks like you are unlucky in your choices of values for the five given variables. Try setting $\gamma$ and $\rho$ so that $\gamma + \rho < 1.$ Or perhaps set $us = 1$.

Comment: @Semiclassical that is a good idea; I will use desmos to do that and see how it looks like.

Comment: @ElliotG Yes, I am, sorry for the confusion. But I don't believe I confused wolfram alpha as I've already entered the fixed values for them (let me know if i'm wrong).

Comment: @ElliotG Not particularly, I just wanted to verify it. I followed my supervisor's (vague) instructions and solving for c was the most likely scenario based on his code and instructions. However, it could very well be he meant solving for s, but I wanted to see if the first scenario was correct.

Comment: Hi @DavidK, why would you recommend particularly those bounds?

Comment: I was trying to find some minimal changes you could make to your parameters to get a solution. You showed two sets of values; $(1-\alpha)c^\rho+\alpha s^\rho$ was greater than $1$ for the first set and not much less than $1$ for the other; but then you raised this expression to the power $\frac{1-\gamma}\rho-1$, which was negative in both cases, and it seemed this might limit how large $\alpha s^{\rho-1} ((1-\alpha)c^\rho + \alpha s^\rho)^{((1-\gamma)/\rho) - 1}$ could be (because it would be largest at $c=0$ and could only get smaller as $c$ increased).

Comment: But the details are worked out much more completely in the accepted answer.

Comment: @DavidK thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's rename $us$ to $u$, since it's more common to work with single-character variable names in math (and it makes it easier to read). The equation is
$$\alpha s^{\rho-1}\big[(1-\alpha)c^\rho+\alpha s^\rho\big]^{\frac{1-\gamma}\rho-1}=u.$$
Now, for every quintuple $(\alpha,s,c,\rho,\gamma)$, there is (exactly) one value of $u$ for which the equation is satisfied. This means that, for at least *some* values of $(\alpha,s,\rho,\gamma,u)$, there is some value $c$ that satisfies the equation: pick some real $c_0$ and some parameters $(\alpha,s,\rho,\gamma)$, set
$$u_0=\alpha s^{\rho-1}\big[(1-\alpha)c_0^\rho+\alpha s^\rho\big]^{\frac{1-\gamma}\rho-1},$$
and then $c=c_0$ will be a root of the equation with parameters $(\alpha,s,\rho,\gamma,u_0)$.

This may not be that satisfying, since it doesn't tell you much about when a solution might exist. Let's try to solve the system. We can first divide by $(\alpha s^{\rho-1})$ to get
$$\big[(1-\alpha)c^\rho+\alpha s^\rho\big]^{\frac{1-\gamma}\rho-1}=\frac{u}{\alpha s^{\rho-1}}.$$
Now, we can take each side to the power of $\frac{1-\gamma-\rho}{\rho}$ to get
$$(1-\alpha)c^\rho+\alpha s^\rho = \left(\frac{u}{\alpha s^{\rho-1}}\right)^{\frac{1-\gamma-\rho}\rho}.$$
This gives
$$c^\rho=\frac1{1-\alpha}\left(\frac{u}{\alpha s^{\rho-1}}\right)^{\frac{1-\gamma-\rho}\rho}-s^\rho\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}.$$
So, depending on your value of $\rho$, this might be solvable (if $\rho$ is an odd integer, there is a root somewhere, while otherwise you probably want the right side to be positive). In general, though, if
$$\left(\frac{u}{\alpha s^{\rho-1}}\right)^{\frac{1-\gamma-\rho}\rho}\geq \alpha s^\rho,$$
then there is a (positive real) solution for $c$.

Edit (to explain the remark on how the solvability depends on $\rho$): Say $\rho$ is some arbitrary real number. Where is $c^\rho$ defined? A priori, it's hard to say how to define exponentation exactly -- it's easy when $\rho$ is an integer and we can just multiply $c$ together a bunch of times, but harder for arbitrary $\rho$. It turns out (and Desmos, for example, will give you a graph of this) that you can define $c^\rho$ for any real $\rho$, as long as $c$ is positive (for an example of why this constraint is reasonable, think about $(-1)^{1/2}$; it turns out we can define exponentiation $x^y$ for all reals, but we lose some nice properties, like the fact that $x^y$ is a real number). These values are always positive, so there is only a solution to $c^\rho=x$ in $c$ for arbitrary $\rho$ when $x$ is positive.

If we're in the special case where $\rho$ is an integer, then we can define $c^\rho$ for all real $c$, and then try to solve for $c$. If $\rho$ is even, $c^\rho\geq 0$ for all $c$, and so we can't solve $c^\rho=x$ for negative $x$. However, if $\rho$ is odd, we can!

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed, step-by-step, helpful explanation! I am just a bit confused with this line: So, depending on your value of ρ, this might be solvable (if ρ is an odd integer, there is a root somewhere, while otherwise you probably want the right side to be positive).

Comment: As my value of $\rho$ has domain (inf,0) to (0,1]. Would that ever work then for the non odd integers here? (apologies if my math notation looks very wrong, as I am an economist by background with subpar math background)

Comment: @GildedCrowEscapee No worries! I've added some explanation of this to my answer.

Comment: Hi sorry I just had one more follow up question! I've looked over your explanation (very thorough, thank you so much) but I still can't seem to understand why the examples I used were wrong.

Comment: To see if I'm getting it right, there are roots for my function when the Right hand side (RHS), (rearranging for the wolfram alpha input in terms of $c^{\rho}$), is positive. When the RHS is negative, there still is a solution, just that $\rho$ has to be an odd integer?

Comment: @GildedCrowEscapee Yes that's correct. For example, in your first example (with $s=40$, $\alpha=0.5$, $\rho=0.5$, $\gamma=2$, $u=3$), the quantity $$\left(\frac{u}{\alpha s^{\rho-1}}\right)^{\frac{1-\gamma-\rho}\rho}$$ is very small (about $2\times 10^{-5}$), while $\alpha s^\rho$ is about $3.2$, so the inequality doesn't hold.

Comment: gotcha, thanks so much!